# How to compare two histograms of different bits

Tags: image-processing, graphics, histogram2d

I have two histograms `200X200` of `8` bit image and one is `800X800` of `16-bit`. How can I compare them? Is it even possible to compare them or not?

Comment: How does 16-bit image corresponds to 8-bit? Is 16-bit monochrome? `200X200` - is it image size or you really need bi-dimensional histogram?  Give more details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can compare these two histograms. First convert the 16 bit image into 8 bit through normalization then compare these two.